# Not able to click on xpath or use selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[This is the field im trying to enter my email in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adp7T.jpg)This is the first time I've run into this problem...for some reason I'm not able to select by XPath or any of the other selector methods. Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone know a fix to this?

```
url = 'https://www.tbs.com/conanpop'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
email = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/fieldset[1]/input")))
email.send_keys("email")
```

Comment: tehre is no input field in the url , its redirecting to internatinal.tbs

Comment: so what url should I use? sorry I'm a bit new to coding

Comment: ad screen shot of the fied you are trying to interact with there is no email field in that page

Comment: Add correct url

Comment: I believe that's on your end, I think it's a USA only website. After switching my VPN to something out of the US it also redirected me, but when on a US IP address it did not

Comment: I navigated to https://www.tbs.com/conanpop - but couldn't find email input or the XPATH you are using.

Comment: just added a picture